# How can I replace newline or \r\n with <br/>?

Tags: php, html, line-breaks, nl2br

I am trying to simply replace some new lines and have tried three different ways, but I don't get any change:

```
$description = preg_replace('/\r?\n|\r/', '<br/>', $description);
$description = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br/>", $description);
$description = nl2br($description);
```

These should all work, but I still get the newlines. They are double: "\r\r". That shouldn't make any of these fail, right?

Comment: Why do you have bare `\r` linebreaks? AFAIK even MacOSX switched to `\n`.

Comment: They're coming from a client's CSV.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove line breaks (no characters!) from the string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757671/how-to-remove-line-breaks-no-characters-from-the-string)

Answer (score 149, accepted):

There is already the [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) function that **inserts** `<br>` tags before new line characters:

Example ([codepad](http://codepad.org/0mRHhdWn)):

```
<?php
// Won't work
$desc = 'Line one\nline two';
// Should work
$desc2 = "Line one\nline two";

echo nl2br($desc);
echo '<br/>';
echo nl2br($desc2);
?>
```

But if it is still not working make sure the text `$desciption` is double-quoted.

That's because single quotes do not 'expand' escape sequences such as `\n` comparing to double quoted strings. Quote from PHP documentation:

> **Note**: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

Comment: Look closer, he the OP specifically shows that they attempted to use `nl2br` and that it didn't work.

Comment: Just tried to run nl2br on a string with double carriage returns, and it worked fine.

Comment: Look at my edit @ThomasMcCabe. I've added some (maybe) useful info.

Comment: Please note that `nl2br` does **NOT REPLACE** but instead **INSERTS** before newlines, which LEAVES the nl characters and ADDS br before them.

Comment: but if we have a file with line breaks and we want to read it by a php script and interpret those break lines , how to do it ?

Answer (score 73):

Try using this:

```
$description = preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/", '<br/>', $description);
```

Comment: a faster alternative could be `$description = str_replace(["\r\n", "\r", "\n"], "<br/>", $description)` taken from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20717751/2431281)

Comment: (One could also use just [`/\R/` for all CR/LF](https://nikic.github.io/2011/12/10/PCRE-and-newlines.html) linebreak combinations.)

Answer (score 19):

You may have real characters "\" in the string (the single quote strings, as said @Robik).

If you are quite sure the '\r' or '\n' strings should be replaced as well, I'm not talking of special characters here but a sequence of two chars '\' and 'r',  then escape the '\' in the replace string and it will work:

```
str_replace(array("\r\n","\r","\n","\\r","\\n","\\r\\n"),"<br/>",$description);
```

Comment: nl2br is nice but this actually works (for my json stuff), thanks!

Answer (score 10):

**Try this:**

```
echo str_replace(array('\r\n', '\n\r', '\n', '\r'), '<br>', $description);
```

Comment: Read about PHP [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). [`'\r\n'`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) is not the same as [`"\r\n"`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Comment: Thanks @axiac, I dont have time to test, But you mean It should be something like `"\r\n"` right ?

Comment: This code-only answer is misleading to naive researchers.

Answer (score 6):

`nl2br()` as you have it should work fine:

```
$description = nl2br($description);
```

It's more likely that the unclosed `'` on the first line of your example code is causing your issue. Remove the ' after $description...

```
...$description');
```

Answer (score 6):

nl2br() worked for me, but I needed to wrap the variable with double quotes:

This works:

```
$description = nl2br("$description");
```

This doesn't work:

```
$description = nl2br($description);
```

Comment: What is the explanation?

Answer (score 3):

This will work for sure:

```
str_replace("\\r", "<br />", $description); 
str_replace("\\n", "<br />", $description);
```

Comment: Absolutely incorrect suggestion. "foo\\r\\nbar" will become "foobar" instead of "foo<br/>bar". Prior to replace html renders "foo bar".

Comment: Meh. Works for some specific cases where the input is of a known format.

Answer (score 2):

```
$description = nl2br(stripcslashes($description));
```

Comment: The explanation is missing from this answer.

Comment: The answer from @softcod.com allows to replace the string from a query, for example:<br>
`$description = nl2br(stripcslashes($row["description"]));`<br>
[stripcslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php) returns a string with backslashes stripped off. Recognizes C-like \n, \r ..., octal and hexadecimal representation.

Answer (score 1):

I think `str_replace(array("\\r\\n", "\\r", "\\n"), " ", $string);` *will* work.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using `nl2br`, all occurrences of `\n` and `\r` will be replaced by `<br>`. But if (I don’t know how it is) you still get new lines you can use

```
str_replace("\r","",$description);
str_replace("\n","",$description);
```

to replace unnecessary new lines by an empty string.

Comment: `\r` in `str_replace` seems to replace everything. And furthermore, you should replace it by `<br>`...