# Problem Replacing Literal String \r\n With Line Break in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, backslash

I have a text file that has the literal string `\r\n` in it. I want to replace this with an actual line break (\n).

I know that the regex `/\\r\\n/` should match it (I have tested it in [Reggy](http://reggyapp.com/)), but I cannot get it to work in PHP.

I have tried the following variations:

`preg_replace("/\\\\r\\\\n/", "\n", $line);`

`preg_replace("/\\\\[r]\\\\[n]/", "\n", $line);`

`preg_replace("/[\\\\][r][\\\\][n]/", "\n", $line);`

`preg_replace("/[\\\\]r[\\\\]n/", "\n", $line);`

If I just try to replace the backslash, it works properly. As soon as I add an r, it finds no matches.

The file I am reading is encoded as UTF-16.

Edit:

I have also already tried using `str_replace()`.

I now believe that the problem here is the character encoding of the file. I tried the following, and it did work:

```
$testString = "\\r\\n";
echo preg_replace("/\\\\r\\\\n/", "\n", $testString);
```

but it does not work on lines I am reading in from my file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF-16 is the problem. If you're just working with raw the bytes, then you can use the full sequences for replacing:

```
$out = str_replace("\x00\x5c\x00\x72\x00\x5c\x00\x6e", "\x00\x0a", $in);
```

This assumes big-endian UTF-16, else swap the zero bytes to come after the non zeros:

```
$out = str_replace("\x5c\x00\x72\x00\x5c\x00\x6e\x00", "\x0a\x00", $in);
```

If that doesn't work, please post a byte-dump of your input file so we can see what it actually contains.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks! Also, can you tell me where you got the byte values for UTF-16? I failed to find it when I searched earlier.

Comment: If you ignore surrogate pairs, UTF-16 just takes `U+abcd` and encodes it as the 2 bytes `\xab\xcd`. The codes are then just the ASCII bytes for backslash (x5c), 'r' (x72) and 'n' (x6e). 0x0a is the newline you wanted to replace them with

Answer (score 5):

Save yourself the effort of figuring out the regex and try `str_replace()` instead:

```
str_replace('\r\n', "\n", $string);
```

Comment: I should have mentioned in my original question that that does not work either. I'll add that in now.

Comment: @Katfish Use single quotes instead of double.  `str_replace('\r\n', "\n", $string)`

Comment: @Wiseguy I read that on http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html, but it did not make a difference in any of my tests. I have tried it both ways using str_replace and preg_replace.

Answer (score 4):

Save yourself the effort of figuring out the regex and the escaping within double quotes:

```
$fixed = str_replace('\r\n', "\n", $line);
```

For what it is worth, `preg_replace("/\\\\r\\\\n/", "\n", $line);` should be fine.  As a demonstration:

```
var_dump(preg_replace("/\\\\r\\\\n/", "NL", 'Cake is yummy\r\n\r\n'));
```

Gives: `string(17) "Cake is yummyNLNL"`

Also fine is: `'/\\\r\\\n/'` and `'/\\\\r\\\\n/'`

**Important** - if the above doesn't work, are you even sure literal `\r\n` is what you're trying to match?..

Comment: It is definitely what I am trying to match, but I now suspect that the r and n may not be the same r and n that PHP is using. My file uses UTF-16.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = preg_replace('/\\\\r\\\\n/', '\n', $subject);
```

The regex above replaces the type of line break normally used on windows (`\r\n`)  with *linux* line breaks (`\n`).

References:

- [Difference between CR LF, LF and CR line break types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946114/how-to-replace-newline-or-r-n-with-br)
- [Right way to escape backslash [ \ ] in PHP regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15369828/797495)
- [Regex Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/dAGKpF/1)

Answer (score 1):

I always keep searching for this topic, and I always come back to a personal line I wrote.

It looks neat and its based on RegEx:

```
 "/[\n\r]/"
```

PHP

```
 preg_replace("/[\n\r]/",'\n', $string )
```

or

```
 preg_replace("/[\n\r]/",$replaceStr, $string )
```

Comment: You should (re)read the question! They want to replace **literal string** `\r\n` with a linefeed `\n`. Your regex repaces `\n` or `\r` with `\n`