# Regular expression for strings in double quotes not working?

Tags: php, regex, file, csv, explode

I'm trying to get all strings wrapped in double quotes with this regexp:

```
"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"
```

I already tried it on this site: http://www.phpliveregex.com/ and it works, but when i put it in my php code like this:

```
if( preg_match('/"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"/', $input_line, $output_array) )
{
.
.
.
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 15
```

what am i missing?

**SOLVED:**

AS mario pointed out, a backslash was being escaped by PHP I got it working like this:

```
if( preg_match('/"(?:[^"\\\]|\\.)*"/', $sLine, $matches) ){
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: The backslash escapes itself in PHP double or single quoted string context. `preg_match` will only see one backslash before the `]`.

Comment: See also: [Right way to escape backslash \[ \ \] in PHP regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11044136)

Comment: thank you so much @mario I'd been trying to solve this for a couple of hours and I finally got it working. :D

Answer (score 3):

The most reliable way to define regexes in PHP is like so:

```
$regex = <<<'REGEX'
/"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"/
REGEX;
```

Admittedly, it's not the most readable, but it ensures that the string is passed as-is to the regex engine and not interpreted by PHP in any way.