# PHP Regex for Windows Directory - preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to validate a user text entry for a directory based on Windows, there is no directory picker of sort, it is just a text field.

I have written the following Regex using http://regex101.com/ which works adequately for my needs:

```
^[a-zA-Z]\:[\/,\\].{1,}
```

Which will match for example the following directories in the online tool:

```
C:/Users/Charlie/Dropbox
D:/Users/Bob/Quotes
F:/Quotes
```

The problem is, when using it in my application, `preg_match` does not match any of the above.  It does not return true, and the `preg_last_error()` returns `0` which also indicates a false return value.

The exact code used is:

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]\:[\/,\\].{1,}/', $directory)) { }
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: whats in $directory?

Comment: @Chris Any of the directories shown above, none of them work.  Have echoed them on the server side (directly before the `preg_match`) and they print exactly as expected.

Comment: try to define an output array and print it.. preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]\:[\/,\\].{1,}/", $directory, $output_array);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use quadruple backslash to match a literal backslash here:

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]\:[\/,\\\\].{1,}/', 'C:/Users/Charlie/Dropbox')) {
//                             ^^^^
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/LdW4HI)

Otherwise, the backslash is just escaping the `]` and that ruins the regex character class.

Note that instead of `{1,}` you can just use `+` quantifier that means *1 or more occurrences* and that you do not have to escape the colon.

I also do not understand why you have a comma in the character class, the character is treated as a literal. I think you just want to match either `\` or `/` with `[\/,\\\]`? Then, the whole regex would look like

```
'/^[a-zA-Z]:[\/\\\\].+/'
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/Zw1OeX)

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!  Though it's worth noting that I actually had to use a quadruple backslash, the triple seems to escape the final quote somehow, leaving the rest of the file in quotation marks.  I have now replaced the `more than one` with the `+` quantifier.  Comma was intended as a separator between the two characters yes, realise now that was incorrect, have updated this now.  I have tested it and it's all working perfectly, thanks again.

Comment: I have found a [post explaining that both 3 and 4 backslashes can be used to match a literal ``\``](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15369828/3832970) but it really recommends using 4 backslashes to match a literal ``\``. I updated the answer accordingly. I think the 3 escapes work the same way as in Python - when an escape sequence cannot be interpreted as such, the backslash is treated as a literal. Perhaps, not in all cases - such as yours.