# Regex - backslash cannot be escaped inside a character class, why?

Tags: php, regex, escaping, backslash, character-class

I've got a short and simple PHP script, in which I want to look for every series of two or more backslashes inside a string, and replace it with a single backslash:

```
<?php
    $link = 'www\\root\\\\test\\';
    echo preg_replace('/[\\]{2,}/', '\\', $link);
?>
```

So I guess that I actually escaped all the backslashes properly, but when I run the code, it gives me back an error that says that the terminating `]` bracket could not be found. So it seems to me that this one is escaped instead of the backslash, which confuses me. Does escaping a backslash inside a character class actually take different methods than that?

Comment: You need 4 backslashes to match a literal backslash.

Comment: Yeah I just found out :P

Comment: You could just search for it in Google. Very [easy to find](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15369828/3832970).

Comment: Hmm... strange, because I didn't find anything.

Comment: [Backslash PHP regex](https://www.google.pl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=backslash%20php%20regex) => First result?

Comment: I didn't link my search with PHP first since I didn't suspect the problem to be connected with that first... welp.

Answer (score 0):

Ah alright, so I came across an answer myself:

```
preg_replace('/[\\\\]{2,}/', '\\', $link);
```

I need to double escape it, since PHP needs to escape it by itself first.