# how to match the back slash in the regular expression

Tags: php, regex, laravel, validation, preg-match

I want my user password have the rule like:

1. at least one alphabet, at least one number.
2. can include special characters (almost all special characters in
   keybord)
3. length more than 8.

this is my regular expression

```
/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d!"#$%&'()*+,-.\/:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]{8,}$/
```

but it does not match the **back slash** .
for example ,the password "3e5t1qa2w\" will fail.

I use laravel(php framework) validation ,so the full code is this:

```
        'password' => array(
            'sometimes',
            'required',
            'between:8,32',
            'regex:/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d!"#$%&\'()*+,-.\/:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]{8,}$/'
        ),
```

here is the real code
[image]

and this one which use two back slash doesnot work too.
[image]

Does someone knows why?

Comment: I believe you need to escape the backslash with another backslash.

Comment: yes I do, like ......[back slash back slash]........ but didnot work

Comment: `/` is a slash or forward slash; ``\`` is a backslash.

Comment: you really need to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords

Comment: [\\] should be [\\

Comment: @MateoConLechuga yes I did it. I have added a image in my question. it does not work ,cannot match "1qa2w/"

Comment: Edited my comment above; the ] causes it to close too early for the single chars you wanted to match

Comment: You want a length more than eight but the example password you've provided is only six characters, for starters.

Comment: @bugfroggy  I'm sorry it's just a mistake."1qa2ws3e/"does not match too.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution didn't work for me in Laravel 5.4., but using 4 backslashes did (at the near end). I'll leave it here if someone has the same problem:

```
/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d!"#$%&'()*+,-.\/:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~\\\\]{8,}$/
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/d3tCBq/2)

Answer (score 0):

this one worked:

[image]

As MateoConLechuga said, the "]" may cause the problem. so I escape the "[" and "]" with back slash which meas they are just the "character".

and this link [Right way to escape backslash [ \ ] in PHP regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044136/right-way-to-escape-backslash-in-php-regex]) helped me that to match back slash i have to write it for three(or four) times.