# PHP preg_match_all doesn't match an escaped quote

Tags: php, regex

This code:

```
<?php
    $string = "\"single quote";
    preg_match_all("/\"/im", $string, $m);
    $all_quotes = count($m);
    preg_match_all("/\\\"/im", $string, $m);
    $escaped_quotes = count($m);

    echo "<pre>";
     echo "<b>string:</b> $string<br>";
     echo "<b>all quotes:</b> $all_quotes<br>";
     echo "<b>escaped quotes:</b> $escaped_quotes<br>";
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Is supposed to match all quotes, then match all escapes quotes, and echo the results.
For some reason, for string `"single quote` it echoes both one quote and one escaped quote, however the pattern `/\\\"/im` matches nothing when executed in http://regexr.com with same string.

Comment: The `"\""` does not contain a backslash. Check [this demo to see how to declare a backslash in a PHP string literal](http://ideone.com/c2In3Z).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right way to escape backslash \[ \ \] in PHP regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044136/right-way-to-escape-backslash-in-php-regex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited:

Ok, so first of all, you are getting count from `preg_match_all` as return value. The way you are doing it now will always show you `1` because `preg_match_all` returns array (with one element in your case).

As Wiktor Stribiżew stated, you need to adjust your regex too

```
preg_match_all("/\\\\\"/im", $string, $m);
```

---

I'm not 100% sure that I understand your question but I'll try to answer it.

You are probably expecting to see `\"` in your `$string` variable, right?

But that's not the case. PHP will remove that backslash before saving your string. It's only hint for PHP that you want to get literal `"` and that you are not trying to end string here.

In case you want (for any reason) get `\"` , you have to use code like this:

```
$string = "\\\"single quote";
```

Comment: No, the $string is perfectly fine and should be `"single quote`

Comment: @WearyAdventurer so what do you expect from that code? Should it show one quote and zero escaped quotes?

Comment: Yes, 1 quote and 0 escaped quotes.

Comment: @WearyAdventurer updated

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: *You regex is fine* is not true. `preg_match_all("/\\\"/im", $string, $m);` matches unescaped quotes because `"\\\""` is actually ``\"`` pattern that matches a `"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is fine for OPs task. He wants to match literal `\"` string.

Comment: To match a quote, one needs `preg_match_all("/\"/im", $string, $m);`. If the string is `\"`, then the `preg_match_all("/\\\"/im", $string, $m);` will only match `"`, and not ``\"``.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew point for you. Two more backslashes.