# Find a substring inside a string with special characters PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a complex string like this

```
{},\"employees\":{},\"idIwant\":{\"2545\":{\"attributes\":{\"offset\":9855,
```

I need the sweet `2545` out from this string, I tried using regex, and strpos but it doesn't play nice with lots of colons, bracket, slashes. Is it possible to extract the number after `idIwant`i.e `2545` ?

This is actually coming from a website's source code, and this is not a json but a redux state string.

Comment: This is actually coming from a source code, and this is not a json but a redux state string.

Comment: Can you load/parse the JSON string? Please post a complete excerpt. Is it always `idIwant`, or will there be other keys/value types? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Should you need it, Here is a cheat sheet of some regex  examples https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work if `idIwant` has only numbers.

```php
$string = '{},\"employees\":{},\"idIwant\":{\"2545\":{\"attributes\":{\"offset\":9855,';

preg_match('/idIwant.*?(\d+)/', $string, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

[Test](https://regex101.com/r/1SAAKb/1)

Answer (score 2):

Isolate the digits after the match like this:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0hmvp))

```
$string = '{},\"employees\":{},\"idIwant\":{\"2545\":{\"attributes\":{\"offset\":9855,';

echo preg_match('~"idIwant\\\":{\\\"\K\d+~', $string, $out) ? $out[0] : 'bonk';
```

Output:

```
2545
```

Keeping the `"` and `\"` around your sought key is important so that you are matching the whole targeted keyword (no inadvertent substring matching).

`\K` restarts the fullstring match so that you don't need to bloat the output array with unnecessary elements.

Php requires 3 or 4 `\` to represent one in the pattern.  (Here's some breakdown: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15369828/2943403)

p.s. Alternatively, you can force the leading portion of the pattern to be literally interpretted with `\Q..\E` like this:

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/NBkiB)

```
echo preg_match('~\Q\"idIwant\":{\"\E\K\d+~', $string, $out) ? $out[0] : 'bonk';
```

Or if you are scared off by so many metacharacters, you could reduce the stability of your pattern and just match the search string, then match one or more non-digits, then forget the previously matched characters, then match 1 or more digits:

```
echo preg_match('~idIwant\D+\K\d+~', $string, $out) ? $out[0] : 'bonk';
```

Answer (score 1):

most easy way is:

```
$String ='{},\"employees\":{},\"idIwant\":{\"2545\":{\"attributes\":{\"offset\":9855,';

$arr1 = explode('"idIwant\":{\"', $String);
```

if you ouput `$arr1[1]` you would get:

```
string=> 2545\":{\"attributes\":{\"offset\":9855,';
```

you need:

```
$arr2 = explode('\":{\"', $arr1[1]);
```

and you would get on `$arr2[0]`:

```
string=> 2545
```

if the string have a strict syntax

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to get that desired digits, one would be an expression similar to:

```
.+idIwant\\":{\\"(.+?)\\.+
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hsAkqX/1/)

#### Test

```
$re = '/.+idIwant\\\\":{\\\\"(.+?)\\\\.+/m';
$str = '{},\\"employees\\":{},\\"idIwant\\":{\\"2545\\":{\\"attributes\\":{\\"offset\\":9855,';
$subst = '$1';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```