# preg_replace not working with object variable PHP

Tags: php, regex, oop, object

i have tried many solutions but couldn't figure out the issue. I have a object with some properties. This is my object

```
object(room)[16]
 public 'id' => string '144323'
 public 'jobId' => string '115141'
 public 'name' => string 'Room 1'
 public 'description' => string 'This is\r\nMy test'
 .....
 .....
```

I am trying to remove `\r\n` from description and here is my code for that

```
$noSymbols = preg_replace('~[\r\n]+~', ' ', $room->description)
```

Weird thing is if i change `$room->description` with `This is\r\nMy test` then i get my output as `This is My test` but with php variable, it doesn't work and giving me output as `This is\r\nMy test`.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? is there any error?

Comment: No error, but code doesn't remove `\r\n`

Comment: What do you mean, "with php variable"? Please paste the code that doesn't give you the expected result.

Comment: Code is already above. `$room->description` is the variable i am talking about. if i echo `$noSymbols` then i am getting string with \r\n

Comment: Do you mean like this `$noSymbols = preg_replace('~[\r\n]+~', PHP_EOL, $room->description)`

Comment: The duplicate demonstrates how to escape your literal newline characters without `preg_quote()`.

Comment: As well as: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7098536/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`preg_quote()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to escape the regex special characters.

A line in the `preg_quote` API doc says:

> The special regular expression characters are: . \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) {
> } = ! < > | : - #

Since you have the `\` in your regex which is a regex special character, you `preg_quote()` them and then match them like below:

```
<?php

$o = new stdclass();
$o->description = 'This is my\r\ntest';
echo preg_replace('/['.preg_quote('\r\n').']+/',' ',$o->description);
```

Comment: @Harpreet The function call is not actually necessary, the fix can be done without.  https://3v4l.org/AaXqK

Comment: @mickmackusa It's ok to use the function as well, no harm.

Comment: @mickmackusa I actually meant it just for it's usage and I have amended it since it was ambiguous in terms of truth(as English is not my first language). Also, preg_quote() is anyways better if OP wants to add some more characters for the replacement, else he will need to pay attention to whether the new chars have meta characters or not if done manually.