# Issue replacing trailing text in text area

Tags: php, html

I'm having an issue whenever I enter text into a text area and submit it to my database.  The text automatically gets a `<br />` tag tacked onto the end of the input.  I'm not sure why and whenever I try to do the `str_replace`, it only works the first time.

Keep in mind that I have text pre-placed in the text area from a query in order to be able to edit it.

```
$query->text = str_replace("&lt;br /&gt;", "", $query->text);
```

```
<textarea id= "custom" name="text" rows = "10" column = "50">
    <?php echo $query->text; ?>         
</textarea>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946114/replace-r-n-with-br

Comment: Also, this should only be done when displaying the text. Just store new lines in the DB. The DB shouldn't concern itself with how the text will be used by the client.

Comment: Errrrr, I didn't mean to put \r\n, I meant to just replace it with "".  I don't want any breaks or new lines at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "it only works the first time?"

Comment: Then you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760816/remove-new-lines-from-string

Comment: @merlin2011 It only replaces text on the first table entry I edit.  Every other one after that still has the trailing br tag.

Comment: @Requiem, Then I would assume you are running this in some kind of loop. Please show that loop in your question.

Comment: There is no loop.  This is just set up in MVC and just consistently calls upon a row and queries for the data when a button is pressed.

Comment: Did you try logging the value of `$query->text` before calling the function, so you can at least verify the exact string before you try the replace?

Comment: I've checked the string multiple times.  Can anyone explain to me first why the "&lt;br /&gt;" tag shows up in the first place?

Comment: try to coding in single line without any line-break, ` <textarea><?php echo $query->text; ?></textarea> `