# PHP - including attribute in shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

This may seem like a Wordpress problem but I think it's PHP specific rather than Wordpress. My problem is in the `// Code` block I think. Here is my code:

```
function display_app_rating( $atts ) {

// Attributes
extract( shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'app' => '',
    ), $atts )
);

// Code
//return '"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id='.($app).'"';
$json_url = '"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id='.($app).'"';
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$result = json_decode($json, TRUE);
foreach ($result['results'] as $key => $value) {
    return '<p class="appstore rating">Average rating '.$value['averageUserRating'].' out of 5 from '.$value['userRatingCount']. ' users.</p><p class="appstore price">Current Price '.$value['currency'].$value['price'].'</p>';
}
}
add_shortcode( 'apprating', 'display_app_rating' );
```

If I hardcode an app ID as the `$app` variable it works fine and if I comment my code out and uncomment the `return...` line it returns the correct URL. My question is how can I get the `$app` variable appended to the URL and working via my shortcode which is

```
[apprating app="439438619"]
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: $json_url = "http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=$app" should work. You have single quotes around the string which doesn't inline the variable. I have no experience with wordpress, can you verify that $app is set correctly from the extract?

Comment: Hi Hammerstein, it doesn't work unfortunately having tried it. When I simply return that line as it is displayed it inlines the URL correctly with the variable inside the quotes as part of the URL.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you want to return after each iteration- push the results into a variable and just return once.

```
$result = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$block = '';
foreach ($result['results'] as $key => $value) {
    $block .='<p class="appstore rating">Average rating '.$value['averageUserRating'].' out of 5 from '.$value['userRatingCount']. ' users.</p><p class="appstore price">Current Price '.$value['currency'].$value['price'].'</p>';
}

return $block;
```

Comment: Thank you Adam, I may be misunderstanding but I appreciate your input and no doubt your code will improve mine in that block. The problem I have though is getting my $app variable as defined by the shortcode into the URL which happens before this?

Comment: It sounds like you should split this function up... try separating this into get_app_rating(), set_app_url(), and display_app_rating() or similar.

Comment: I think between you all you've got this working for me thank you very much. I added your block return idea but didn't need to create individual functions.

Comment: Right on =) The reason I suggest individual functions is it makes testing easier- something to consider moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`extract()` is not recommended](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99604/12615). To check for query values in the URL, use [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

The following first checks if the URL contains `?app_id=something`, if so the result will output it. If the URL doesn't contain it, the shortcode attribute will be used `[apprating app="something"]`. Otherwise, it prints an error message:

```
add_shortcode( 'apprating', 'shortcode_so_25877611' );

function shortcode_so_25877611( $atts, $content )
{
    $args = shortcode_atts( 
        array(
            'app'   => '',
        ), 
        $atts
    );

    $result = 'No app id.';
    $app = (int) $args['app'];

    if( !empty( $_GET['app_id'] ) )
        $result = (int) $_GET['app_id'];
    elseif( $app )
        $result = $app;

    $json_url = "http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=$result";

    return $return;
}
```

The test shortcode on a post was as follows, and then appending the query var to the URL:

```
With id: [apprating app="1234"]

Without: [apprating]
```

<sub>PS: as [noted by Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877611/php-including-attribute-in-shortcode/25877846#25877846), your `return` must be outside the `foreach` loop.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Can you assist further if possible. Where does the rest of my code fit with this? e.g. the `$json_url = '"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id='.($app).'"';
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);` etc I can see the returning of the $app variable but it doesn't appear attached to the URL?

Comment: I've added an example. You were using the quotes wrong, learn the difference between single and double quotes in PHP, it's important.

Comment: Thank you, I have a working version incorporating your comments. I did think I was using quotes correctly but I wasn't because I was approaching it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I finished up using. It's a mixture of the various responses. Seems to work fine. Guidance appreciated.

```
add_shortcode( 'myrating', 'display_my_app_rating_89' );
function display_my_app_rating_89( $atts, $content )
{
$args = shortcode_atts( 
    array(
        'app'   => '',
    ), 
    $atts
);

$result = 'No app id.';
$app = (int) $args['app'];

if( !empty( $_GET['app_id'] ) )
    $result = (int) $_GET['app_id'];
elseif( $app )
    $result = $app;

$json_url = "http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=$result";
//normal PHP version commented out and wordpress version activated - appears to be Wordpress best practice.
//$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
//wordpress version
$json = wp_remote_retrieve_body (wp_remote_get($json_url));
$result = json_decode($json, true);
$block = '';
foreach ($result['results'] as $key => $value) {
$block .='<span> ... whatever I wanted to return from JSON URL plus my HTML here ... </span>';
}
return $block;
}
```

Comment: I have a supplementary question. One of the fields returned by the JSON URL contains `\n` for line breaks. This function strips them out and returns a simple block of text. I would like to retain the line breaks - so I guess convert `\n` to `<br>` tags. Is there a simple edit to achieve this?

Comment: I have tried these methods - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946114/replace-r-n-with-br but with no luck inserting after the line `$json = wp_remote_retrieve_body (wp_remote_get($json_url));`

Comment: Got it - all the sample code was using double quotes, I needed to switch to single for whatever reason `$json = str_replace(array('\r\n','\r','\n'),'<br/>', $json);`