# How to remove \r\n charecters from sending mail?

Tags: php

```
$txt = str_replace("\r\n", ' ', $txt);
```

I gave this code in my mail sending function. Still it shows "\r\n" in mail message. How to remove this "\r\n".

Comment: you mean literally the characters `'\r\n'`? are they always one after the other like this or should you replace them one by one?

Comment: Use `nl2br()` to replace from `<br>`, Or see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5946256/2236219)

Comment: `str_replace(array('\r', '\n', '\r\n', "\r", "\n", "\r\n"), "", $txt);` (*Covers the string representation as well*)