# Adding Linebreaks to text pulled from SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

When I get data from a MySQL database and echo it using PHP viewing the HTML source show it like this

```
<div class="Desc">testing lines
new line
another                     </div>
```

How do I get it to add  on the end of the lines so it shows correctly in the browser

I want to end up with something like this

```
<div class="Desc">testing lines<br/>
new line<br/>
another line<br/>                       </div>
```

I have tried `<?PHP echo nl2br($text) ?>`
but that doesn't work

Comment: Could you give some more code? Every \n\r should convert to a <br/> with nl2br().

Comment: What exactly are you storing in $text?

Comment: This is a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946114/how-to-replace-r-n-with-br

Comment: I have tried nl2br in your example and it works

Answer (score 0):

yes you are correct - it does work, i was viewing the source or the wrong page after adding the nl2br code

my mistake

thanks anyway