# Saving \n as <br> to database from textarea

Tags: php, mysql, database, textarea

I tried this but it's not chaning new lines to < br >

`<textarea name="addesc" id="addesc"><?php echo $data['addesc']; ?></textarea>`

`$data['addesc'] = preg_replace("/\r\n|\r/", "<br />", $_POST["addesc"]);
$data['addesc'] = trim($data['addesc'])`

As such there's no `$_POST["addesc"]` on the post.php page. There's `$_POST["do"]`. I tried it too. No results.

Comment: Please do not edit the solution into your question. Instead, [mark one question as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) or if none of the existing answers solved the problem, post your own an accept it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a php function for that called [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.nl2br.php).

Btw. searching for "new line to br" would have been very easy and brings up certain related topics on SO and the php manual of `nl2br`:

[How to replace \r & \n with <br/>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946114/how-to-replace-r-n-with-br)

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but that function is not going to help me. I need to save the new lines as < br > from a textarea to DB. Does it really boil down to just using a function?

Comment: Indeed it is, yes: Check this example: http://viper-7.com/kpumMr

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask you what exactly is TEXTAREA_INPUT in my case? Is it the `<?php echo $data['addesc']; ?>` and if it is how do I use it with the code on that page?

Comment: Got it. This did it: `$data['addesc'] = htmlentities(nl2br($data['addesc']));`

Comment: Remove the ´htmlentities´ call! This just to visualize the ´<br/>´s when showing them in a browser.