# PHP-REGEX - Replace line break with <br> within pre tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have

```
<pre>
Line one
Line two
Line three
Line four
Line five
Line six
</pre>
```

If I strip the pre tags, it becomes

Line one
Line two
Line three
Line four
Line five
Line six

What would be the regex for replacing new lines with a br so that after stripping pre tag each line is separate.

Comment: So your string currently has `\n` newline characters and you'd like to replace them with `<br>`?  What do you see when you `var_dump($string)` the string?

Comment: Look at the `nl2br` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace \r & \n with <br/>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946114/how-to-replace-r-n-with-br)

Comment: @BeetleJuice running:

$html = preg_replace("/\R/",'<br/>',$html);

does it fine across the entire document, adding <br><br>. I would however, want this to be run within the pre tags only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At each position you need to check whether or not you are inside a valid `<pre>` tag:

```
~(?s)(?<!<pre>)\R(?!</pre>)(?=((?!<pre>).)*</pre>)~
```

Explanation:

```
(?s)                # Set DOT_ALL modifier
(?<!<pre>)          # Assert if we are not immediately after an opening <pre> tag
\R                  # We need new-lines only
(?!</pre>)          # Not followed by a closing </pre> tag
(?=                 # Beginning of a positive lookahead
    ((?!<pre>).)*   # To look if we are not behind an opening <pre> tag (inside a <pre> tag)
    </pre>          # Which has a closing </pre> tag
)                   # End of lookahead
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/jA4pD7/1)

***Note***: It doesn't provide expected results if you have nested `<pre>` tags (!)

But if you are comfortable to work with `DOM` then there is a more suitable solution for this:

```
<?php

$html = <<< HTML
<div>
<div>
test
test
test
</div>
<pre>
Line one
Line two
Line three
Line four
Line five
Line six
</pre>
</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED  | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$preTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('pre');

foreach ($preTags as $key => $pre) {
    $pre->nodeValue = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '~*~*', $pre->nodeValue);
}

echo str_replace("~*~*", '<br />', $dom->saveHTML());
```

Output:

```
<div>
<div>
test
test
test
</div>
<pre><br />Line one<br />Line two<br />Line three<br />Line four<br />Line five<br />Line six<br /></pre>
</div>
```